# How to configure Rails 3 assets pipeline to just copy all app/assets contents to public/assets in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, production-environment

I need from my Rails 3 app just to copy the dir and file tree structure from app/assets to public/assets, flattened (all images, javascripts etc. must go just to public/assets, maintaining their subfolder structure). Don't ask me why.

I don't want merging CSS and JS files into a single files, don't want digests, don't want compression.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do isn't to *configure* the asset pipeline; it's to *disable* it.

You can do this by setting `config.assets.enabled = false` in your `config/application.rb`.

Then instead of putting all of your assets in `app/assets`, just put them in `public` and refer to them as normal.